# sapply not applying a function created to all rows in R dataframe

Tags: r, function, sapply, strsplit

I have the following dataframe in R and am trying to use a stringsplit function to the same to yield a different dataframe

```
DF
A         B       C
"1,2,3"        "1,2"
  "2"     "1"
```

The cells of the dataframe are filled with characters. The empty spaces are blank values. I have created the following function

```
sepfunc<-function(x){strsplit(as.character(x, split= ","))[[1]][1]}
```

The function works neatly when i use it on a single column

```
sapply(DF$A, sepfunc)

 [1] "1" "2"
```

However, the following command yields only a single row

```
sapply(DF, sepfunc)
 A        B       C
"1"       NA      "1"
```

The second row is not displayed. I know I must be missing something rudimentary. I request someone to help.

The expected output is

```
  A        B       C
 "1"       NA      "1"
 "2"      "1"       "NA"
```

Comment: You are only subsetting the first element of `strsplit` i.e. 1st row with `[[1]]`.  Not clear about your expected.  What do you want as output

Comment: yes. But the split works for a single column even when I am subsetting the first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only want to extract the first part before the `,` you can also do

```
sapply(DF, function(x) gsub("^([^,]*),.*$", "\\1", x))

#       A   B  C  
# [1,] "1" NA "1"
# [2,] "2" NA "1"
```

This extracts the the first group (`\\1`) which is here marked with brackets. `([^,]*)`

Or with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
sapply(DF, function(x) str_extract(x, "^([^,]*)"))
```

Answer (score 3):

When we do the `strsplit`, the output is a `list` of `vector`s.  If we just subset the first `list` element with `[[1]]`, then the rest of the elements are skipped.  Here the first element corresponds to the first row.  But, when we do the same on a single column, it is looping through each element and then do the strsplit.  It will not hurt by taking the first element `[[1]]` because the `list` is of length 1.  Here, the case is different.  The number of `list` elements are the same as the number of rows for each of the columns.  So, we need to loop through the `list` (either with `sapply/lapply` - former gives a vector depends on the case, while latter always return `list`)

```
sapply(DF, function(x) sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ","), `[`, 1))
#      A   B   C  
#[1,] "1" NA  "1"
#[2,] "2" "1" NA
```

---

Let's look this more closely by splitting the codes into chunks.  On each column, we can find the output as `list` of splitted `vector`s

```
lapply(DF, function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ","))
#$A
#$A[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3"

#$A[[2]]  
#[1] "2"


#$B
#$B[[1]]
#[1] NA

#$B[[2]]
#[1] "1"


#$C
#$C[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2"

#$C[[2]]
#character(0)
```

When we do `[[1]]`, the first element is extracted i.e. the first row of 'A', 'B', 'C'

```
lapply(DF, function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ",")[[1]])
#$A
#[1] "1" "2" "3"

#$B
#[1] NA

#$C
#[1] "1" "2"
```

If we again subset on the above, i.e. the first element, the output will be `1 NA 1`.

Instead we want to loop through the `list` and get the first element of each `list`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of this

```
lapply(X = df, FUN = function(x) sapply(strsplit(x = as.character(x), split = ","), FUN = head, n=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, notice that your `sepfun` should always give an error:

```
sepfunc<-function(x){strsplit(as.character(x, split= ","))[[1]][1]}
```

`split` should go with `strsplit`, not `as.character`, so what you meant is probably:

```
sepfunc<-function(x){strsplit(as.character(x), split= ",")[[1]][1]}
```

Second, the question of data sanity. You have character variables stored as factors, and missing data stored as empty strings. I would recommend dealing with these issues before trying to do anything else. (Why do I say `NA` is more sensible here than an empty string? Because you told me so. You want `NA`'s in the output, so I guess this means that if there are no numbers in the string, it means that something is missing. Missing = `NA`. There is also a technical reason which would take a bit longer to explain.)

So in the following, I'm just using an altered version of your `DF`:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=c("1,2,3", "2"), B=c(NA, "1"), C=c("1,2", NA), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

(If DF comes from a file, then you could use `read.csv("file", as.is=TRUE)`. And then `DF[DF==""] <- NA`.)

The output of `strsplit` is a `list` so you'll need `sapply` to get something useful out from it. And another `sapply` to apply it to all columns in a data frame.

```
sapply(DF, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ","), head, 1))
#      A   B   C  
# [1,] "1" NA  "1"
# [2,] "2" "1" NA
```

Or step by step. Before you can  `sapply` a function over all columns of a data frame, you need it to give meaningful results for all the columns. Let's try:

```
sf <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ","), head, 1)
# and sepfunc as defined above:
sepfunc<-function(x){strsplit(as.character(x), split= ",")[[1]][1]}

sf(DF$A)
# [1] "1" "2"
# as expected

sepfunc(DF$A)
# [1] "1"
```

Notice that `sepfunc` uses only the first element (as you told it to!) of each column, and the rest is discarded. You need `sapply` or something similar to use all elements. So as a consequence, you get this:

```
sapply(DF, sepfunc)
#  A   B   C 
# "1"  NA "1"
```

(It works, because we've redefined empty strings as NA. But you get the results only for the first row of each variable.)

```
sapply(DF, sf)
# A   B   C  
# [1,] "1" NA  "1"
# [2,] "2" "1" NA
```